# Defining bind in the double barrelled continuation Monad in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, continuation-passing

Trying to define bind for this monad in haskell.
If the calculation succeeds it calls the SCont continuation, if it fails it calls the FCont continuation.

```
type M a = SCont a -> FCont -> Answer
type SCont a = a -> FCont -> Answer
type FCont = () -> Answer

result :: a -> M a
result x ks kf = ks x kf

(>>=) :: M a -> (a -> M b) -> M b
```

Comment: Have you tried using typed holes? Where did you run into trouble?

Comment: You can't define "bind" for a bare type synonym. You need to make it a newtype, and then declare it an Instance of Monad.

Comment: Also, why would you want `() -> Answer` instead of just `Answer`, and what is `Answer` anyway?

Comment: Yeah I know I need to make it an instance of Monad, but putting Haskell formalities aside, how would I define it. Answer can be anything.

Comment: I'm trying to learn to define bind given a Monad. This is from an old problem sheet. Why I would want to do this in practice is fairly irrelevant to me

Comment: Start by ditching `FCont`. It's silly noise. Use `Answer` instead. Have you tried typed holes yet? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Trying typed holes right now, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Using typed holes didn't really do much except tell me that haskell bind expected a M b type on the RHS of the def. (which is obvious given the type signature). Ditching FCont just gives me the monad of continuations, in which (x >>= f) k = xm (\x -> f x k). However I can't see how this helps me

Comment: Perhaps I'm using typed holes wrong

Comment: The reason I suggested ditching `FCont` is that `() -> a` is "morally equivalent" to `a`, for any type `a`. Because Haskell is lazy, the near-isomorphism almost preserves performance characteristics. So the only differences are: 1. `() -> a` has an extra bottom element observable only by `seq` and 2. The result of `() -> a` may not be memoized (but that's implementation-dependent). In a strict language like ML, the distinction matters much more.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, thanks for trying to help

(xm >>= f) ks kf = xm (\a f' -> f a ks f') kf

Answer (score 1):

The definition you give of `SCont` is weird to me: how comes the successful continuation takes the failure one as an argument? Plus, given you `return` and `bind`, it looks like the failure one is threaded all the way down the call tree and... applied to the success one in case you hit a return.

I would expect the 'double barrelled continuation Monad' to be defined like so:

```
module SFCont where

import Control.Monad

newtype SFCont r a = SFCont { sfCont :: SCont r a -> FCont r a -> r }
type SCont r a = a -> r
type FCont r a = r

instance Functor (SFCont r) where
  fmap f (SFCont c) = SFCont $ \ ks -> c (ks . f)   

-- this will be obtained from the definition of the `Monad` instance
instance Applicative (SFCont r) where
  pure  = return
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad (SFCont r) where
  return a = SFCont $ const . ($ a)
  m >>= f  = SFCont $ \ ks kf -> sfCont m (\ a -> sfCont (f a) ks kf) kf
```

We can find a systematic way of defining it (and its cousin where failure can take an element of an error type `e`) by reasoning up to isomorphism and noticing that:

```
SCont r a -> FCont r a -> r    ~{ unfolding SCont, FCont }
(a -> r) -> r -> r             ~{ r iso (() -> r) }
(a -> r) -> (() -> r) -> r     ~{ uncurrying }
((a -> r), (() -> r)) -> r     ~{ ((a -> r), (b -> r)) iso (Either a b -> r) }
(Either a () -> r) -> r        ~{ Either a () iso Maybe a }
(Maybe a -> r) -> r            ~{ folding MaybeT, Cont }
MaybeT (Cont r) a
```

And now, we can leverage existing instances by writing down this iso:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module SFCont where

import Data.Functor.Identity
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.Trans.Cont

newtype SFCont r a = SFCont { sfCont :: SCont r a -> FCont r a -> r }

type SCont r a = a -> r
type FCont r a = r

newtype SFCont' r a = SFCont' { sfCont' :: MaybeT (Cont r) a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

to :: SFCont r a -> SFCont' r a
to m = SFCont' $ MaybeT $ ContT $ \ k -> Identity $
       sfCont m (runIdentity . k . Just) (runIdentity $ k Nothing)

from :: SFCont' r a -> SFCont r a
from m = SFCont $ \ ks kf -> runIdentity $
         (runContT $ runMaybeT $ sfCont' m) (Identity . maybe kf ks)

instance Monad (SFCont r) where
  return  = from . return
  m >>= f = from $ to m >>= to . f
```

In the case where the failure continuation could take an element of an error type `e`, you'd follow the same process and arrive at the stack `EitherT e (Cont r) a` for your iso.